# srand() in nested loop same results

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested, srand

So my task is to produce randomly generate weights and profits for batches of items(for 0/1 knapsack problem). I represented the batches in arrays in batch[]. My problem is that:

1. rand() is not generating unique random values in the second for loop. Is it because of the nested for loops?
2. The second for loop assigns values to p[j] and w[j] but as it follows j, at each iteration assigning of values start at j, how can I start it from 0 each time?

The output:

```
| 231 |25
| 231 |25
| 231 |25
| 231 |25

| 0 | 0
|19 | 4
|19 | 4
|19 | 4
|19 | 4
|19 | 4



main(){
srand(time(NULL));
int i, j, t;
int batch[] = { 4, 5 };
int sizeOfBatch = sizeof(batch) / sizeof(batch[0]);

for (i = 0; i < sizeOfBatch ; i++){


    int *p = (int*)calloc(batch[i], sizeof(int));   
    int *w = (int*)calloc(batch[i], sizeof(int));   

            for (j = 0; j < batch[i]; j++){                 

        p[j] = rand() % 500;
        printf("\n| %d  ", p[i]);
        w[j] = rand() % 100;
        printf("| %d  ", w[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to `p[j]` (and `w[j]`) and printing `p[i]` (and `w[i]`); your problem is unrelated to `srand()` or `rand()`.

```
        p[j] = rand() % 500;      // assign to p[j]
        printf("\n| %d  ", p[i]); // print p[i]
        w[j] = rand() % 100;
        printf("| %d  ", w[i]);
```

---

In the 2nd loop, everytime the loop starts, `j` begins at `0`

```
            for (j = 0; j < batch[i]; j++) {
                // first time through the loop, j is 0
            }
```

Comment: I guess looking at the code for hours makes things even worse. Everything's fixed now. How stupid am I. It was right anyways I guess. Can't believe myself.

Comment: The importance of good variable naming: instead of `i` and `j`, you could use `batchnum` and `testnum` :)